# Ensure two Pandas DatetimeIndexes are the same?

Tags: python, pandas

I have run into an issue when comparing two `DatetimeIndex`'s with different lengths in an `assert` like the following:

```
In [1]: idx1 = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-12-31',freq='D')

In [2]: idx2 = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-11-01',freq='D')

In [3]: assert (idx1 == idx2).all()
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ad2cfd6d11c2> in <module>()
----> 1 assert (idx1 == idx2).all()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1.dev_dcd9df7-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.pyc in wrapper(self, other)
     75         result = func(other)
     76 
---> 77         return result.view(np.ndarray)
     78 
     79     return wrapper

AttributeError: 'NotImplementedType' object has no attribute 'view'
```

Which is fine if this is not implemented, yet, but is there some **pandas** way of doing this?

**Note:**
I have used the following with success:

```
In [3]: assert list(idx1) == list(idx2)
```

So, the following also works:

```
In [3]: assert list(df.index) == list(testindex)
```

But I would like to know if there is a more `pandas`-ish way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: idx1 = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-12-31',freq='D')

In [3]: idx2 = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-11-01',freq='D')

In [4]: idx3 = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-12-31',freq='D')

In [5]: help(idx1.equals)
Help on method equals in module pandas.tseries.index:

equals(self, other) method of pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex instance
    Determines if two Index objects contain the same elements.


In [6]: print(idx1.equals(idx2))
False

In [7]: print(idx1.equals(idx3))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You now have [pandas.Index.Difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html), which might suit your needs.

It is as simple as this:

```
idx_common = idx1.difference(idx2)
```